# Is code coverage available in VS2012 for metro-style apps?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, code-coverage

I am using Windows 8 Pro and Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate (both RTM).

I create a Metro-style class library, and then a corresponding unit test library. Both target WinRT (not the .NET framework).

I can run unit tests fine, but when I attempt to "Analyze code coverage for all tests", the output window comes up with the results of the rebuild, and that's it. The Code Coverage Results window is all grayed out.

From reading on the web, some have alluded to the idea that code coverage is not enabled for WinRT assemblies, but I cannot confirm. I have also tried creating a .testsettings file, like was needed in VS2010 and explicitly turn on code coverage, and I got the same results.

Can anyone confirm or deny that code coverage is not available for WinRT-targeted assemblies, in VS2012 RTM?? I'm just trying to figure out if I'm missing some setting - or if it's not possible.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12812454/winrt-code-coverage/15553968#15553968

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible at this stage due to the sandboxed nature of WinRT apps.

P.S. It's on the list of things the team is looking to resolve in the near future (no, I don't have a timeframe for it)

Comment: I know it's only been a little over a month since this question was posed, but has any progress been made on this front?

Comment: Actually it is possible to hook a profiler into a Windows 8 app (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davbr/archive/2013/01/09/writing-a-profiler-of-windows-store-apps.aspx) A code coverage profiler such as NCover or OpenCover could use this technique - the question is really should they?

Comment: How does the sandbox prevent code coverage from being collected?  Can a WinRT app write (even if you have to give it permission) to a file?  If so, why can't it write coverage data to such a file?

Comment: Apparantly a WinRT app can write to files when given permission.  So it is possible for such an app to write test coverage data, if the app can collect it.