# Code coverage for Windows 8 metro application unavailable?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, code-coverage

I'm developping a metro application on VSUltimate and have some test methods.

I want to know if it's now possible to see the code coverage?
I red this topic but it was posted on 2012...
[Is code coverage available in VS2012 for metro-style apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12029433/is-code-coverage-available-in-vs2012-for-metro-style-apps)
Has anything changed?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is code coverage available in VS2012 for metro-style apps?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12029433/is-code-coverage-available-in-vs2012-for-metro-style-apps)

Comment: Voting to close; if there was more information, it would be updating in the existing question.

Comment: There is a [feature](https://github.com/sawilde/opencover/issues/144) open for OpenCover but not sure of the demand or even if it is required. Most coverage of apps can/should be done via unit tests and you can always try and use the Portable Class Libraries.